# helm harbor is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: object required

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3, harbor

I've successfully pushed some locally built helm chart to harbor private helm registry using below commands:

```
helm registry login private.harbor.com
helm push chart-version.tgz oci://private.harbor.com/some-project
```

Now I fail to add helm repo (for the goal of installation of the pushed helm chart) using below commands:

```
$ helm repo add helm-test2 oci://private.harbor.com/some-project/
Error: looks like "oci://private.harbor.com/some-project/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: object required
$ helm repo add helm-test2 oci://private.harbor.com/some-project/helm-test-repo
Error: looks like "oci://private.harbor.com/some-project/helm-test-repo" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: object required
$ helm repo add helm-test2 https://private.harbor.com/some-project/helm-test-repo
Error: looks like "https://private.harbor.com/some-project/helm-test-repo" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type repo.IndexFile
$ helm repo add helm-test2 https://private.harbor.com/some-project
Error: looks like "https://private.harbor.com/some-project" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type repo.IndexFile
```

How to `helm repo add` Harbor OCI helm repository?

It's important to note that docker images are stored alongside pushed helm charts at  `private.harbor.com/some-project/`.

Alternative way that worked is uploading helm chart under `Helm charts` tab in `some-project` in Harbor UI.

Afterwards, below commands for adding and installing the chart worked:

```
helm repo add helm-test https://private.harbor.com/chartrepo/some-project
helm repo update helm-test
helm install chart helm-test/chart --version 1.5.0
```

I would use this method, but have no idea how to push to `https://private.harbor.com/chartrepo/some-project`, pushing to `oci://...` worked only after following [this](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/issues/13170) github link.

Below attempts failed:

```
helm push chart-version.tgz oci://private.harbor.com/chartrepo/some-project
Error: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
helm push chart-version.tgz https://private.harbor.com/chartrepo/some-project
Error: scheme "https" not supported
```

I'm using latest helm (3.8) and harbor version (2.5)